# Error while building Hadoop native library for compression codec on cygwin/windows

Tags: hadoop, makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to use Hadoop compression codec on windows environment. However, as mentioned in Hadoop documentation, native libraries need to be built for any platform other than Linux.

I'm building native library for compression codec from Cygwin following the steps mentioned here:
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.18.3/native_libraries.html#Building+Native+Hadoop+Libraries

But getting this error:
(last few lines of the log)

```
 [exec] configure: WARNING: jni.h: present but cannot be compiled
 [exec] configure: WARNING: jni.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
 [exec] configure: WARNING: jni.h: see the Autoconf documentation
 [exec] configure: WARNING: jni.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
 [exec] configure: WARNING: jni.h: proceeding with the preprocessor's result
 [exec] configure: WARNING: jni.h: in the future, the compiler will take precedence
 [exec] configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------ ##
 [exec] configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to the AC_PACKAGE_NAME lists.  ##
 [exec] configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------ ##
 [exec] checking for jni.h... yes
 [exec] checking zlib.h usability... yes
 [exec] checking zlib.h presence... yes
 [exec] checking for zlib.h... yes
 [exec] checking Checking for the 'actual' dynamic-library for '-lz'...
 [exec] checking zconf.h usability... yes
 [exec] checking zconf.h presence... yes
 [exec] checking for zconf.h... yes
 [exec] checking Checking for the 'actual' dynamic-library for '-lz'... (cached)
 [exec] checking fcntl.h usability... yes
 [exec] checking fcntl.h presence... yes
 [exec] checking for fcntl.h... yes
 [exec] checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
 [exec] checking for string.h... (cached) yes
 [exec] checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
 [exec] checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
 [exec] checking for memset... yes
 [exec] checking whether strerror_r is declared... yes
 [exec] checking for strerror_r... yes
 [exec] checking whether strerror_r returns char *... no
 [exec] configure: creating ./config.status
 [exec] config.status: creating Makefile
 [exec] config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in
```

> BUILD FAILED C:\cygwin\usr\local\hadoop\build.xml:596: The following
> error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\cygwin\usr\local\hadoop\build.xml:645: exec returned: 1

I have also renamed all the Makefile to Makefile.in but still cannot get past this error.
Can anybody please help me fixing this up.

Makefile does exist in the `haddop/src/native` folder and if I build it using `./configure`, it is fine, however, it does not generate any jars.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible: "The native hadoop library is supported on *nix platforms only. **The library does not to work with Cygwin** or the Mac OS X platform."

Comment: I think that is true only for pre-built libraries. If you want to use theses libraries for any other platform, you are required to build it from the source.